# How to tell web server that some HTTP client (which is not known officially) supports HTML5?

Tags: html, http, httpclient

How to tell web server that some HTTP client (which is not known officially) supports HTML5? As I know, HTTP servers check what browser and version. But if I want to send HTTP request with header `"User-Agent: SomeUnknownAgent"` - how I must notify remote HTTP server that this "SomeUnknownAgent" supports HTML5? Here are sample `"User-Agent"` values:

```
Chrome 6.0.472.63: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3
Firefox 3.6.10: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10
Firefox 4.0 Beta 6: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0b6) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0b6
Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Opera 10.63: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.6.30 Version/10.63
Safari 5.0.2: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Safari/533.18.5
```

I found these in common: `Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1;`. Maybe it is enough to include?

Comment: Why are you doing this to begin with? HTML5 HTML syntax is explicitly backwards compatible for old browsers. Any other new HTML5 features need to be detected client-side to begin with, not server side.

Comment: HTTP server accordingly responds to request. It may not include some features if it detects that browser version is outdated. This is tested on some web servers.

Comment: That would be a server bug. Don't rely on the user agent to check for browser features.

Comment: I agree. But I'm here as client, so `"User-Agent: SomeUnknownAgent 1.0.0.0: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) Gecko/20100101"` is better than only `"User-Agent: SomeUnknownAgent 1.0.0.0"`. Just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. It helped a lot to read [here](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/). So the answer for example could be:

```
"User-Agent: SomeUnknownAgent 1.0.0.0: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) Gecko/20100101"
```

Now HTTP server knows that browser supports HTML5. Of course, if it's rely on `"User-Agent"` field.